# JHipster 3.5.1 How to use data from social login

Tags: jhipster

I found when user registered via social login (Facebook) there are `jhi_social_user_connection` table provided by JHipster team out of the box! However, there is no connection between `jhi_social_user_connection` and `jhi_user tables`.

How can I access and use data stored in `jhi_social_user_connection`? Should I modify some files by hands, add some relation at DB layer?

For example how can I get `image_url` stored in `jhi_social_user_connection` table for current user? Any advice or link to example will be great!